# Laravel, how to use Heartland payment system

Tags: php, laravel

Im using stripe in my laravel application but the owner needs to integrate heartland payment system, I tried to find guide of how to install it into laravel but didn't found
I installed the package by editing composor.json and followed the tutorial here 
https://github.com/hps/heartland-php

but now I don't know how to do it as stripe method (blade view, controller, route ... etc)
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no framework specific 'wrapper' for Heartland so there's no 'Cashier' equivalent. You can take a few tips from the way Cashier is designed though, so it might benefit you reading through the way it's setup. From looking at the Heartland composer.json file it's autoloader seems complete so you should be free to do something like:

```php
$config = new \HpsServicesConfig();
$config->secretApiKey = config('heartland.secret');
// the following variables will be provided to you during certificaiton.
$config->versionNumber = '0000';
$config->developerId = '000000';
$creditService = new \HpsCreditService($config);
```

I grabbed this snippet and slightly modified it from their (slightly old) [charge example](https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/pay-invoice/charge.php). ymmv.

A few tips:

- Setup a heartland.php configuration file and import your keys etc. from .env. This will help your configuration and deployments be consistent.
- Don't be afraid to create your own 'service' class to wrap common things w/ Heartland, especially given the key and configuration objects. As such the above example snippet will probably exist within a factory.
- You'll probably want to setup a test project and experiment with how you build workflows (creating a route/controller/view for your page and then interact with the Heartland SDK and API) before you throw it straight into a bigger in-progress project.